# Get same values of an array and render Vuejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a product array that contain id, name, category, with 5 data. lets assume there are 3 products assign to mobile category and two of them are computer category. **what is the proper way to render those three products on a same category 'mobile'**

```
  let array_e = this.E_Product;  //products array

  array_e.forEach((element) => { 
    var obj = _.find(array_e, (find) => find.category == 'mobile');
    console.log(obj); 
  });
```

finding an object on an array display only one object that caught first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter

```
 let array_e = this.E_Product; 

  array_e.filter((element) =>element.category == 'mobile' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a computed property and provide its value to `v-data-table` or `v-list` component :

```
computed:{

    mobileProducts(){
      return this.E_Product.filter(prod=>prod.category == 'mobile');
    }

}
```

Comment: `(prod=>prod.category == 'mobile');` can you tell what are these `prod`?. no data's are filtered and array cleared

Comment: `prod` is the callback parameter like you did in `(find) => find.category == 'mobile')`